# impossible add Icefaces 3 facet in Eclipse 3.7?

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, richfaces, icefaces

I am trying add Icefaces 3 facet but it is not work correctly, I have created a maven project (WTP=2.0) by maven command, the I have add JSF2,Java 1.6 and Javascript by Eclipse project facet, but when I try to add ICefaces 3 facet then Eclipse not working.

I add .XHTML extension in JSP editor and it work fine if I create a ICefaces project.

*I don´t upload images, sorry, this is a link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/75492946@N02/6785053594/*

In the image above, I press OK button and nothing happens, Icefaces 3 faces doesn´t add.

Otherwise, I download M2Eclipse and I have created a maven project, I followed the same steps above, and everything is fine until I try to add ICefaces 3 facet, with the same result for me.

I can write tag **ui** autocomplete  bacause JSF2 nature add correctly, but I dont write autocomplete tags **ace/ice**

Finally, I could create a Icefaces project but this is not desired by me, because I need a Maven project within Icefaces 3 nature.

any suggestions?

Kinds regards.

==================================================================================

Finally!! I have resolved this problem. It is a very easy solution but I had overlooked. When You need to add Dynamic Web Module facet you must set **Content directory: /src/main/webapp/**

In this way the project preserver standard maven structure y then you could add JSF2 and Icefaces3 facet without problem.

Now, You can create *.xhtml file and autocomplete Icefaces,JSF2 and facelets tags.

**Edit:** The real conflict is the web.xml, it must be version=3.0, only in this way you can do the above steps.

ICefaces 3 releases note say: *This release includes the Mojarra JSF 2.1.4 runtime libraries. Mojarra 2.1.4 introduces a hard depedency on Servlet 3.0 APIs, as a result, it cannot be used on older JEE5 application servers. Mojarra 2.1.3, or Apache MyFaces 2.1.6 should be used in on older JEE5 servers instead.*

In my case I use Mojarra 2.1.3 and the web.mxl is version=2.5, but it conflict because ICefaces 3 eclipse facet somehow related Mojarra 2.14 and web.xml version=3.0

The final solution addition to the above is to user web.xml version=3.0 and libraries provided by Icefaces3 plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start your project as an ICEFaces project, you can convert it to be a Maven project also after it is created.

1. Right click the project in your explorer
2. Select Configure > Convert to Maven project

This has worked for me in the past when I have needed a project to use Maven and other plugins at the same time.

Comment: I unknow this option, but in this way the project has not a standard maven structure (_src/main/java|resources|webapp and src/test/java|resources_). I am afraid I going to decide between _maven structure_ or _icefaces facet_. Thank you very much for your response.

I like to preserve this structure and not have the need to add the folder "webContent" for example.